# Adding vertical spacing in List

Tags: itext, listitem

I am new to ItextSharp Coding, where I have created a list

[image]

using the code

```
 Dim li = New List(12)
    li.ListSymbol = New Chunk(ChrW(&H2022), HeaderFont)
    li.Add(New ListItem("Item 1", DefaultFont))
    li.Add(New ListItem("Item 2", DefaultFont))
    li.Add(New ListItem("Item 3", DefaultFont))
    li.Add(New ListItem("Item 4", DefaultFont))
    li.Add(New ListItem("Item 5", DefaultFont))
    li.Add(New ListItem("Item 6", DefaultFont))
    p1 = New Paragraph("", DefaultFont)
    p1.IndentationLeft = 50
    p1.SpacingBefore = 5
    p1.Add(li)
 myDocument.Add(p1)
```

DefaultFont and HeaderFont are delcared earlier for styling purpose.
So just wanted to know is there a way I can add vertical Spacing between the listed items (Need to add extra space between listed items) using above piece of code..?

Comment: Should I used a table instead and then add Bullets and Text separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ListWithLeading](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ListWithLeading) example.

In this example, I first create a list the way you did:

```
List list1 = new List(12);
list1.setListSymbol("\u2022");
list1.add(new ListItem("Value 1", font));
list1.add(new ListItem("Value 2", font));
list1.add(new ListItem("Value 3", font));
document.add(list1);
```

Note that I add the list directly to the `document`, I don't see any reason why you would wrap it inside a `Paragraph`.

I then create a list the way you want it to be created:

```
List list2 = new List(12);
list2.setListSymbol("\u2022");
list2.add(new ListItem(30, "Value 1", font));
list2.add(new ListItem(30, "Value 2", font));
list2.add(new ListItem(30, "Value 3", font));
list2.setIndentationLeft(60);
document.add(list2);
```

Note that I define the left indentation using the `setIndentationLeft()` method (in C#, this is probably somethink like `list2.IndentationLeft = 60;`) and I change the leading of the `ListItem` objects from the default (which is 1.5 times the font size) to 30.

[image]

Note that the distance between the baselines of two consecutive lines is called the *leading* in PDF terminology. You can define this leading at the level of the `ListItem`.

Comment: Thanks Man.. This makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using itext 7 and I change the space between items with `ListItem` bottom margin.

In my case I wanted the items closer I do this:

```
listItem.SetMarginBottom(-5);
```